# sort a list on strings based on a double value in java

Tags: java, list, sorting

I have a list of strings in the following format

```
["BlahBlahBlahBlah   0.9877"]
["ABCabcABCabcAbc   1.7852"]
```

As you can see between the two is a single space. I cannot change the design due to some restrictions.

What I need to do is to sort the list based on the double number at the end.
Can anyone help me implement this code?

Comment: Implement a custom `Comparator` that only looks at the double value.

Comment: It is customary (and good form) on SO to show what you have tried and ask a specific question. Otherwise it just looks like you want someone to do your work for you.  Put some effort into it, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a single space, but anyway...

```
Collections.sort(yourList, new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        double d1 = Double.valueOf(s1.substring(s1.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1));
        double d2 = Double.valueOf(s2.substring(s2.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1));
        return Double.compare(d1, d2);
    }
});
```

(import java.util.Collections and java.util.Comparator if not already.)

Comment: Depending on list size, this could be quite wasteful due to extra n*(logn - 1) string-to-double conversion.

Answer (score 0):

If you know for a fact that the number will always be the format X.XXXX (five digits and a decimal), you can do something like '

```
String asString = yourString.substring(yourString.length-9,yourString.length-3);
Double asDouble = Double.parseDouble(number);
```